# How can I show articles from my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Im trying to make a article posting system that shows new posts in the index.php and when you click on one it takes you to the artikkeli-sivu.php that shows the whole article. For some reason I cant get the articles to show on artikkeli-sivu.php, but I can get the to show in the index.php. artikkeli-sivu.php gives me this error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "article_id" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-projekti1\artikkeli-sivu.php on line 74.

Below is the index.php, connection.php and here is the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzaCB.png)

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');
include_once('article.php');


$article = new Article;
$artikkelit = $article->fetchAll();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS projekti</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <a id="otsikko" href="index.php">CMS</a>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach ($artikkelit as $artikkelii) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="artikkeli-sivu.php?id=<?php echo $artikkelii['article_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $artikkelii['article_title']; ?> 
                </a><br>
                postattu: <?php echo date('l jS', $artikkelii['article_timestamp']); ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ol>
    </div>      
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the artikkeli-sivu.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

include_once 'connection.php';
include_once 'article.php';

$article = new Article;


if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);
}

    


?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .back-button {
        position: relative;
        top: 500px;
        width: 140px;
        height: 45px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', arial;
        font-weight: 500;
        
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border: none;
        transition: 0.3s ease 0s;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
    }
    .back-button:hover {
        background-color: #24a0ed;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #6bbff2;
        color: #fff;
        transform: translateY(-3px);
    }

    .article-container {
        background-color: white;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px lightgrey;

    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Artikkelit </h1>
<div class="article-container">
    <?php echo $data['article_id'];?>
    
</div>

<a class="back-link" href="index.php"><button class="back-button">Back</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the article.php

```
<?php


class Article {
    public function fetchAll(){
global $pdo;

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artikkelit");
$query->execute();

return  $query->fetchAll();
     
    }
    public function fetch_data($article_id){
        global $pdo;
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artikkelit WHERE article_id= ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
            $query->execute();
    
            return  $query->fetchAll();
         
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "cms";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', '');
    echo "<h3>Yhteys luotu!</h3>";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit('Epäonnistui');
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: What is "this error"? Can you share the error message in text form, along with your attempts to resolve it?

Comment: Here is the error: Warning: Undefined array key "article_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-projekti1\artikkeli-sivu.php on line 74. I've tried to check if everything is written correctly in the artikkeli-sivu.php, because I can get the articles to show in the index.php

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, `artikkeli-sivu.php` does not contain any line 74 that could trigger that problem

Comment: I changed it now

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? In `artikkeli-sivu.php`, `$data` is not defined after all if no ID is used. And it might be empty if a non-existing ID is used

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$data` instead of checking `$data['article_id']`? Maybe your query didn't work for some reason, or maybe `$data` is an object not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `fetch_data` function, this line

```
return  $query->fetchAll();
```

returns all the rows the query selects. Because it doesn't know if there will be 0, 1 or more rows, it returns an array of rows. So even though in your case you're expecting only 1 row, you'll get an array of rows.

Therefore, `$data['article_id']` won't work because `$data` isn't a single row with named properties, it's an array of rows. You can use `var_dump($data);` to debug and see the structure.

Two possible fixes:

1. Quick and dirty - just get the first row from the array and echo the article ID from that:

   `<?php echo $data[0]['article_id'];?>`

OR

2. A bit neater - make your `fetch_data` function only retrieve a single row from the database:

   `return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Also you should check whether `$data` is populated before trying to access it - otherwise you'll get an error or warning if URL didn't contain an ID, or the ID doesn't exist in the database.

e.g. (assuming you used option 2 above)

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php 
    if (isset($data) {
      echo $data['article_id'];
    }
    else
    {
      echo "No data found";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**Documentation reference:**

- [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)